# VS2015 Code Coverage not working with tests in ASP.NET Core 1.0 (formerly known as ASP.NET 5)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, code-coverage, xunit

I have a an ASP.NET Core 1.0 (previously known as ASP.NET 5) solution with a couple of Class Library (Package)'s and an ASP.NET MVC6 project.

I have a test library using the new XUnit 2.0 which supports Core 1.0.

However, for some reason my code coverage is producing zero results when running it on all of my tests which are passing.

By default, ASP.NET Core 1.0 projects are built in-memory by the runtime and no artifacts are persisted to disk. So in the settings I enabled "Produce all outputs on build" for each project in the solution. Now when I build I see the pdb and dll files being output to the artifacts folder. I thought for sure code coverage would work after this, but still no results.

Maybe code coverage just simply doens't work with the new .NET Core 1.0. If anyone has some information on this that would be great.

Comment: Ever figure it out?

Comment: Nope, unless the solutions below work. I am just waiting it out.

Comment: Did you try my answer ?

Comment: I got this working today with XUnit & OpenCover. Can you post your test project's `project.json`? Maybe I can see what's different between our builds.

Answer (score 5):

I'm able to get code coverage with **OpenCover 4.6.166** using this configuration :

### project.json sample

```
{
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"dependencies": {
    "<project under test>": "1.0.0-*",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300"
},
"frameworks": {
    "net451": {
        "dependencies": {
            "Moq": "4.5.16"
        }
    },
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
        "dependencies": {
            "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
                "version": "1.0.0",
                "type": "platform"
            },
            "moq.netcore": "4.4.0-beta8",
            "System.Diagnostics.Process": "4.1.0",
            "System.Diagnostics.TraceSource": "4.0.0"
        },
        "imports": [
            "dnxcore50",
            "portable-net451+win8"
        ]
    }
},
"testRunner": "xunit"
```

}

I use the myget CI feed my NuGet.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
        <clear />
    <add key="api.nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <!--<add key="aspnetmaster" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v3/index.json" />-->
    <!--<add key="aspnetlatest" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2" />-->
        <add key="AspNetVNext" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcidev/api/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Restore dependencies with **--infer-runtimes** option:

```
dotnet restore --infer-runtimes
```

Then use OpenCover with this command line :

```
OpenCover.exe -target:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" -targetargs:" test ""<your project path>\project.json"" -f net451 -xml ""test\ChatLe.Repository.Test\xunit-results.xml"" -nologo -parallel none" -output:"<your coverage .xml path>" -register:user -filter:"+[*]* -[xunit*]* -[*]*Migrations.*" -returntargetcode
```

Note the **-f net451** switch is important, it says to dotnet to use the net451 framework. To cover netcoreapp1.0 use **-f netcoreapp1.0**.

In my console output, I can see those result :

[image]

Comment: It seems that since then OpenCover started to work with `netcoreapp1.0` as well, at least it works fine in my project. I blogged about how I set it up here: https://blog.markvincze.com/setting-up-coveralls-for-a-net-core-project/

Answer (score 3):

I got a .NET Core project with working code coverage using xUnit 2.*, Appveyor, OpenCover and Coveralls, but it had to be extended to .NET Platform Standard. You can see the results on the relevant open source library [here](https://github.com/invio/Invio.Extensions.DependencyInjection).

Some notable conclusions:

1. I couldn't find a way to get OpenCover to pay attention to 'portable' debugType *.pdb files. I had to use the legacy, Windows-only 'full' *.pdb format. **This is done by setting 'debugType' to 'full' under 'buildOptions' in your project's 'project.json' file.**
2. **I had to run OpenCover on Windows, and it had to run via some version of the traditional .NET Framework.** If you haven't yet, configure your non-test project to use .NET Platform Standard instead of .NET Core explicitly, like I did [here](https://github.com/invio/Invio.Extensions.DependencyInjection/blob/e843bcb60805c7cf7c2e85af820ff30f70654810/src/Invio.Extensions.DependencyInjection/project.json#L30). Then, in your test project, break apart your .NET Core and your traditional .NET Frameworks, like I did [here](https://github.com/invio/Invio.Extensions.DependencyInjection/blob/e843bcb60805c7cf7c2e85af820ff30f70654810/test/Invio.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Tests/project.json#L20). Assuming you use .NET Platform Standard 1.6, you would use `net463` where I have `net46`.
3. **Run OpenCover using the traditional .NET Framework via the `dotnet test` command line tool, not the xUnit console runner.** You can see my code coverage generation (and submission) powershell script [here](https://github.com/invio/Invio.Extensions.DependencyInjection/blob/master/coverage.ps1). Where I specify `net46`, you would specify the version you used in your test project (presumably `net463`).

Here's the script pulled from source. You may or may not need to adjust the `filter` argument with respect to your dependencies.

```
nuget install OpenCover -Version 4.6.519 -OutputDirectory tools
nuget install coveralls.net -Version 0.7.0 -OutputDirectory tools
.\tools\OpenCover.4.6.519\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe -target:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" -targetargs:" test ""test\Invio.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Tests\project.json"" -f net46" -register:user -filter:"+[*]* -[xunit*]*" -returntargetcode -output:opencover_results.xml
.\tools\coveralls.net.0.7.0\tools\csmacnz.Coveralls.exe --opencover -i .\opencover_results.xml
```

Technically, this isn't testing .NET Core. This is testing the traditional .NET Framework's interpretation of an otherwise .NET Core project. However, if you do not do any conditional compilation based upon which framework you're using, the code coverage results will be identical.

*A minor word of caution: if you look at the example repository, you'll see that I have a debugType of `portable`, not `full`, for my project.json file. That's because I am using Travis CI for Linux & Mac OS X builds, and that fails when you use `full` debugTypes. I got around this by setting mine programmatically [via a powershell script](https://github.com/invio/Invio.Extensions.DependencyInjection/blob/master/set-debug-type.ps1) running after my build [on appveyor](https://github.com/invio/Invio.Extensions.DependencyInjection/blob/master/appveyor.yml).*

Comment: Alternative to this technique is a Shared Project compiled for "Classic Framework" and I like it more since it is more declarative to other team members and debugging of conditional compilation is much more easy.

But thank you for information about Coveralls. Nice cloud.

Answer (score 2):

I've got it working XUnit.

Important things to note:

- xunit.runner.json is where your xunit configurations go
- Microsoft.CodeCoverage package is needed to run code coverage in visual studio

You will get all tests shown in the Test Runner Explorer. You can also analyze code coverage with the Visual Studio menu item. Only thing I haven't got working is code coverage highlighting: [code coverage highlighting in .net core visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480100/code-coverage-highlighting-in-net-core-visual-studio)

This is my project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "copyToOutput": {
      "include": [ "xunit.runner.json" ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives": "4.1.1",
    "xunit": "2.1.0",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
    "ClanService": { "target": "project" },
    "Utilities": { "target": "project" },
    "UnitTests.Configuration": { "target": "project" },
    "Microsoft.CodeCoverage": "1.0.2"
  },
  "testRunner": "xunit",
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.1"
        }
      },
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.4",
        "portable-net451+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed this blog and was able to get some results, with opencover, althought I don't think it's correct.

And I need to investigate why the wrong numbers, if you find/found a way to do it, please share.

http://dotnetthoughts.net/measuring-code-coverage-of-aspnet-core-applications-using-opencover/

Answer (score 0):

There is a [thread](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/issues/327) in the OpenCover GitHub repository about this topic. The trick to making it work is noted in a [wiki post](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/wiki/DNX-Support).

> The trick (user supplied) is to use the --lib argument of dnx.exe e.g.
>
> ```
> OpenCover.Console.exe -target:"C:\<path-to-dnx>\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6\bin\dnx.exe" 
>     "-targetargs:--lib c:\projects\<path-to-site>\website\bin\debug\dnx451 --lib
> ```
>
> c:\projects\\common\bin\debug\dnx451 -p
>   c:\projects\\test\Website.Tests test" 
>           -output:coverage.xml 
>           -filter:+[Website]*