# code coverage highlighting in .net core visual studio

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I'm using visual studio 2015, with .NET Core project. I've setup all the unit test properly, the tests run fine, executes fine.

The only thing missing is code coverage highlighting. It used to work with my .Net4.5 application. Am I missing something?

I'm using XUnit with .NET Core. I've added `Microsoft.CodeCoverage`, but that did not seem to have any difference.

This is my project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "copyToOutput": {
      "include": [ "xunit.runner.json" ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives": "4.1.1",
    "xunit": "2.1.0",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
    "ClanService": { "target": "project" },
    "Utilities": { "target": "project" },
    "UnitTests.Configuration": { "target": "project" },
    "Microsoft.CodeCoverage": "1.0.2"
  },
  "testRunner": "xunit",
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.1"
        }
      },
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.4",
        "portable-net451+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone else having any luck with this?

Comment: What is your edition of Visual studio ? Only Enterprise edition has code coverage highlighting.

Comment: I'm on Enterprise

Comment: Changing your `debugtype` build option from `portable`to `full` should fix your issue.

Comment: @nulltoken You are a genius! Post this as an answer and I'll upvote it a thousand times. :)

Comment: @l3utterfly Done ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of .NET Core LTS 1.0.3, changing your `debugtype` build option from `portable` to `full` should fix your issue.