# How can I get the code coverage for XUnit tests on the TFS?

Tags: tfs, asp.net-core, xunit

How can I get the code coverage for XUnit tests on the TFS for ASP.NET Core? I don't quite find any good information on the internet.

Any help?

Comment: Which build are you using? XAML build or Vnext build?

Comment: I use Vnext build

Comment: My company has had success using [OpenCover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover) running over .NET Core applications by making our source projects .NET Platform Standard compliant and then running the tests on a Windows CI server using the traditional .NET Framework. It looks like OpenCover can be ran from TFS, so that would be a way to accomplish this. I wrote up a detailed answer on how to accomplish it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39324025/735679

Answer (score 0):

For now, the default code coverage option it's only support with **VS test.** To get this with XUnit tests, you may have to use 3-party tool to achieve it. Such as using **OpenCover** like comment suggested to generated a xml report file.

And then either publish the xml test result to server or using the customization of the build summary to display the report. Detail steps you can refer the answer of *Robert K* in this question [Display OpenCover results in TFS 2015 build Summary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906487/display-opencover-results-in-tfs-2015-build-summary)

Comment: **OpenCover** is working in **nUnit Test**, how could we use the OpenCover for a **xUnit Test ?** Kindly assist me.